# How can I make an Ember action considered a trusted event so that window.open succeeds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, cross-domain, deezer

My ember app must open a window (via an external JS API) and the corresponding API instruction should be called by a controller action, since it should then transition to another route.

My problem is that when the action is triggered, the window won't open. It will only open from a code dealing directly with a [*trusted event*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events), i.e. a click from the user.

So, getting away from Ember and debugging with jQuery and supposing that the `window.open()` instruction is in the `MyLib.login()`, this code **A** works:

```
$('#mybutton').click(() ->
  MyLib.login()
)
```

but this code **B** doesn't:

```
$.myNamespace = {
  myLoginFunction: () ->
    MyLib.login()
}

$('#mybutton').click(() ->
  $.myNamespace.myLoginFunction()
)
```

and an ember action won't work either, generating the same code as **B**, which after debugging, is that `window.open()` will return an undefined object.

My questions are:

- Is there a way I can make code **B** work? (which would make a lot of sense for factorizing reasons)
- Is there a way an Ember action can also work?

PS: for more transparency, the lib I'm talking about is Deezer's JavaScript SDK.

PPS: pardon my CoffeeScript

Comment: Are you sure that action can actually open window? http://jsbin.com/nocuhadejo/1/

Comment: Try `$('#mybutton').click($.myNamespace.myLoginFunction)`

Comment: You are right, an action can open a window, cf. my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what you are fighting here is the pop-up blocker that most browsers have enabled by default these days.

I am only familiar with the way the pop-up blocker works in Firefox (originally implemented in [bug 252326](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=252326) and not changed much since then), other browsers are similar however. The idea is simple: pop-ups can only open in response to an explicit user action. This goes beyond trusted events, only mouse clicks and key presses count as such actions. All other pop-ups are considered undesirable and will be blocked.

So, to answer your question:

> How can I make an Ember action considered a trusted event so that window.open succeeds?

Any code running in response to a user action (meaning **synchronous** code execution) is allowed to open pop-ups. As to other code, e.g. delayed actions (including asynchronous callbacks to synchronous code executed in response to a user action) or code responding to application-generated events - the pop-up blocker won't let is pass and there is nothing you can do about it. A web application cannot fake trusted events, just as it cannot circumvent the pop-up blocker at will (either one would be a security issue).

> Is there a way an Ember action can also work?

You have essentially two options:

1. `window.open()` will return `null` in Firefox if blocked (behavior in other browsers might be different). You could detect this and ask the user to add your site to pop-up blocker exceptions. However, most of them will ignore such requests.
2. You change the way your web application works. E.g. you could open an empty pop-up window when the user clicks the "log in" button but only fill it with real content later. Or you could move the login action into the pop-up window. Or you could stop using pop-up windows altogether and display a layer in your main window instead. Your choice.

Obviously, the second option makes more sense and that's what all websites do. Fighting browser's security mechanisms is no fun.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very valuable when debugging my situation. (cf. my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your comments and feedbacks. Nevertheless, working on my problem, I can answer to my own questions.

Ember actions *ARE* considered trusted actions when triggered by a click or other user events.

My problem was kind of stupid. I realized that my `login` function was first calling a `loginStatus` function, the real login being executed in an asynchronous callback depending on the result of the result of the `loginStatus` response. It makes sense that the callback lost the "trusted" attribute.

Comment: And how is your answer different from what I wrote? What you did is exactly my second suggestion.

Comment: It is not exactly what i did but fair enough, I'll try to edit your answer so that it's not misleading (for instance, the "You cannot" needs to be less assertive) and accept it.